# How to ignore directories from a workspace symbol search in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

When searching for a symbol in VSCode across a JS project, it seems to return results from the node_modules:

[image]
How can I omit these?

I've tried adding `node_module` entries into `files.exclude` and `search.exclude` but that seems to have no effect

Answer (score 5):

That's not currently possible, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46718) about it you can follow until solved.

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering the same and decided to develop an extension for easy navigation among workspace files and symbols. Hope it helps somebody.

It is fully customizable so the user can easily decide which folders are included/excluded from the currently opened workspace/project.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbysiec.vscode-search-everywhere

Answer (score -1):

Ignore folders in a certain workspace, you can go to:

`AppMenu > Preferences > Workspace Settings`

Ignore in all your workspaces, go to:

`AppMenu > Preferences > User Settings`

and add the following to your configuration:

```
 "search.excludeFolders": [
            "node_modules",
            ".git",
            ...
        ],
```

Comment: search.excludeFolders is invalid, think that worked in an older version